# Text to HTML produces a lot of spaces in email signature?

Tags: html

Here is an HTML of my signature:

```html
<p class="x_MsoNormal"><strong>Name</strong></p>
<p class="x_MsoNormal"><strong>Title</strong></p>
<p class="x_MsoNormal"><strong>Company</strong></p>
```

But when I copy paste it to my Mailspring client I get huge space between lines.
How can I reduce it? Please advise

Comment: I think it's because `<p>` elements have margins by default. Use `<div>`s for grouping

Comment: also `x_MsoNormal` might define wide margins between elements.

Comment: @FZs thanks, I have tested it and it actually did the job!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `<p>` elements have margins by default. Use `<div>` elements for grouping:

```html
<div class="x_MsoNormal"><strong>Name</strong></div>
<div class="x_MsoNormal"><strong>Title</strong></div>
<div class="x_MsoNormal"><strong>Company</strong></div>
```